# flex air open windowedapplication if closed

Tags: apache-flex, air, window, program-entry-point

I have an Air application (windowedApplication) that uses many windows (window) I would like to be able to open back the main windowedApplication if it was closed from one of the other windows that still exist after the main window is closed. Is this possible ?

Comment: What you try is "active" windowedApplication? Is this correct?

Comment: yes, but once the main windowedapplication is closed, the active method just activate one of the remaining window

Comment: But keep in mind that if you close the "windowedApplication" close the application? From what I understand what you're trying to do is not possible.